# Contact list not sort in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch my phone contacts in alphabetical sort order.Its fetch name by fast but not getting sort order .I tried **ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY + " ASC"** also **ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC"** but not getting good result.

My code is

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
while (phones.moveToNext())
{
    String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
   Log.e("Tag ","Name " + name);

}
phones.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to get the sort order of your phone contacts like this:

```
int sort_order=Settings.system.getInt (getApplicationContext ().getContentResolver (),"android.contacts.SORT_ORDER");
```

now your cursor query will be like this:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,sort_order);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get contacts in alphabatical order:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```